# #value! error in cells containing user defined functions

Tags: c#, excel

I need to open an Excel workbook using C# as read-only. No problems there. But if that workbook was saved with autofilter on, I need to turn it off using c# so I can read the worksheet values into my class. The problem is, if a cell has a user-defined function in it, that cell will show the #VALUE! error when autofilter is turned off instead of it's correct value. This is not a problem if I manually turn off autofilter just using Excel. So I know there is no problem with the user-defined functions themselves.

Here's what I am doing:

```
   Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
   Excel.Workbook CIRworkbook;
   var missing = Missing.Value;

   bool openAsReadOnly = true;
   CIRworkbook = (Excel.Workbook)(app.Workbooks.Open(xlsFile, missing, openAsReadOnly, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing));

   app.get_Range("A:IV", missing).Worksheet.AutoFilterMode = false;
   app.CalculateFull();
```

The app.CalculateFull() line has no effect on removing the #VALUE! error.

Comment: Is the UDF contained in the workbook or in an add-in?  I seem to recall that add-ins are not loaded when Excel is opened via automation.

Comment: The UDFs are in a module in the workbook.

Comment: Have you tried making the Excel instance visible?  Does that fix the issue?   Or try app.CalculateFullRebuild() instead.  Just did a quick test and I didn't see your problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following syntax to get all the cells that contains values in the sheet regardless of the auto-filter on/off or the actual filter used.

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
Worksheet currSheet = excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
object[,] objData = (object[,])currSheet.UsedRange.Value2;
```

the `Value2` member holds the underline content of the cell/Range. if you're looking for the visible string displayed to the user, use `Text` property.